# How do I prove that $B(V,W)$ is complete?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V,W$ be banach spaces and $B(V,W)$ be the space of bounded linear operators equipped with the operator norm.

How do I prove that $B(V,W)$ is complete?

Let $\{T_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $B(V,W)$. I have shown that $T_n$ is pointwise convergent to a bounded operator $T$. However, I am stuck at the stage showing that $||T_n - T||$ converges to $0$.

How do I show this?

Comment: This has been asked before. Please search "dual of normed space is complete" and mimic the proof.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Well.. i saw your hint, but you only illustrated how to prove that $T_n$ is **pointwise convergent** to a bounded operator $T$. Or maybe that post is not what you meant.. Would you give me a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't stare at $||T_n -T||$.

By definition, $||T_n -T||$ is the least number $c$ s.t. $||(T_n -T)x|| \leq c||x||$.

$||(T_n -T)x||=||T_n x - \lim_{m\to \infty} T_m x||=\lim_{m\to \infty}||T_n x - T_m x||$,  since $||\cdot||$ is continuous.

Now we can deduce the information from the Cauchy sequence.